# Angular ui-bootstrap-datepicker change color on click

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using ui.bootstrap.datepicker. How can I change the color of a date when I press a button? The styles for 'full' and 'partially' are applied at the beginning, but when I change 'events', I see no change.

```
$scope.events = [
        {
            date: new Date(),
            status: 'full'
        },
        {
            date: new Date(),
            status: 'partially'
        }
    ];

vm.open = function () {
        $scope.events[0].date = new Date(2018, 0, 1);
        return $scope.events[0].status;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've done is I've added an [`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) to the element and I'm calling a function every time the model changes (when you click a datepicker button).

Then I filter the events and remove the one with the matching date

**HTML**

```
<div style="display:inline-block; min-height:290px;">
  <div uib-datepicker ng-model="dt" ng-change="clickOnDate(dt)" 
  class="well well-sm" datepicker-options="options"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.clickOnDate = function(dt) {
    $scope.events = $scope.events.filter(function(d) {
        return (
          !(d.date.getFullYear() === dt.getFullYear() &&
            d.date.getMonth() === dt.getMonth() &&
            d.date.getDate() === dt.getDate())
        );
    })
}
```

I'm using the [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method above.

[Demo plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/UIl3SJznzJ3MAB66PU0T?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your intent is, but you can push new items to the `$scope.events` array quite easily:

```
$scope.events.push({
  date: new Date(2018, 0, 1),
  status: 'my-event'
});
```

The `status` property corresponds to a CSS class that you can define as desired, to style the event however you want. For example you can highlight the event like this:

```
.my-event button span {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 32px;
  color: black;
}
```

This will leave you with a small red dot on the specific date, just as the example in the **angular-ui** documentation showcases. If you'd like to highlight the entire button, try this instead:

```
.my-event button span {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

To remove or change the highlighting of events, you might want to clear the `$scope.events` array sometimes (or remove single items):

```
$scope.events = [];
```